# file order loading issue - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

Using [Jquery Upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) I am getting the message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fileupload' in main.js
```

This issue is [known](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/1085) and I followed the instruction to load `jquery.fileupload.js` after `js/upload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js` and `jquery.iframe-transport.js` and `main.js` but I still get this message.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of loading is causing problems, you could use [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) with a callback parameter to load the next library once the first has finished.  Alternatively, you could use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html) to specify loading order of library components.

Answer (score 0):

This is my order of loading scripts... and works very fine

- js/fileupload/load-image.min.js js/fileupload/canvas-to-blob.min.js
- js/fileupload/jquery.iframe-transport.js
- js/fileupload/jquery.fileupload.js
- js/fileupload/jquery.fileupload-process.js
- js/fileupload/jquery.fileupload-image.js
- js/fileupload/jquery.fileupload-validate.js